# ASP.NET - Query value is passed correctly but does not return any results in the query API string

Tags: asp.net, xml, api

I have a form that submit a query to an API. the parameter is passed correctly to the next page and I can print it as a test, but it is not passed to the API query

q='%"&Request.QueryString("id")&"%'

sometimes the result is just generic and does not include the query parameter. I can print it and the parameter is definitely passed to the page but it is just ignored or return an error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ideas on how to fix this? not sure if it is a formatting issue or the way the page is loaded.

This requests the query parameter and displays it on the page as a test (correct value is returned)

Form page:

dim intID as String
intID = Request.QueryString("id")
Response.write(intID)

Result Page:

This is the Query Parameter section:
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/products.xml;q='%"&Request.QueryString("id")&"%'?token=B17495243749DAC9660980F6FB98495928DDX123")

So when I use the browser - copy the link to the url with a parameter e.g. q=spain, I get the correct results but when embedded in the asp.net page, it doesn't work

Comment: Try UrlEncode() on the entire string you are passing into doc.Load()

Comment: I tried encoding it as follow but it doesnt work:                                                dim  url1 as String
dim url as string                                                                                                               url = 'http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/products.xml;q=paris?token=B8DKSKSK185243749DAC9685310F6FEEB7F483UEUEU'
url1  = WebUtility.UrlEncode(url)

Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(url1)